# sql query group by with aggregate

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum, aggregate

Have the following table as an example:

```
    zipcode |  zipsource | patientcount
    -----------------------------------
     81501  |     CMHSP  |   10
     81503  |     CMHSP  |   20
     81505  |     CMHSP  |   30
     81501  |     SMHRMC |   15
     81503  |     SMHRMC |   25
     81505  |     SMHRMC |   35
```

Trying to show only the zipcodes where the patient count is above 20% of total for Source and Source = SMHRMC(normally a parameter but for the example I've selected SMHRMC).  Output table as follows:

```
   zipcode  | zipsource  |  patientcount | Total  | Percent
   --------------------------------------------------------
    81503   |  SMHRMC    |   25          |  75    |  25%
    81505   |  SMHRMC    |   35          |  75    |  47%
```

I've tried multiple queries but at this point I don't think I'm close.  Any ideas?

The query that works is as follows:

```
    select zipcode, 
           zip_source, 
           patient_count, 
           total_count, 
           patient_count *100/total_count as percentage
    from Zip_Count_Source
    cross join (select sum(patient_count) as total_count
                from zip_count_Source
                where zip_source = 'COMHSP') as X
    where zip_source = 'COMHSP' and  patient_count*100/total_count > 1
```

But what I'm having issues with now is that Zip_source can be a multi-value parameter so I change the clauses to zip_source in ('COMHSP', 'SMHRMC') and it works but I want to total_count for each source but not the combined for both sources.  Group By did not work after the where clause. Thanks for all that have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT zipcode, zipsource, patientcount * 100 / total_count
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(patientcount) AS total_count
            FROM mytable
            WHERE zipsource = 'SMHRMC') AS x
WHERE zipsource = 'SMHRMC' AND patientcount / total_count > 0.2
```

The query uses a `CROSS JOIN` in order to link the total count of `patientcount` with the table. Using this count we can calculate the percentage, and filter out any rows not exceeding the desired value.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TUGDNR49776)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
select  t1.zipcode,
        t1.zipsource,
        t1.patientcount,
        t2.total,
        t1.patientcount / t2.total * 100 as percent
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  zipcode, sum(patientcount) as total
            from    yourTable
            group by zipcode
        ) t2
on      t1.zipcode = t2.zipcode
where   t1.patientcount / t2.total > 0.2
```

To filter for a single `zipsource`, you can add a condition to the `where` clause

```
where   t1.patientcount / t2.total > 0.2 and
        t1.zipsource = 'SMHRMC'
```

Answer (score 0):

When joining to another table, there is commonly a join condition to filter out rows preventing a Cartesian product (the contents of one table multiplied by another).  Since the derived table (total) returns a single value, the join condition is unneeded (the contents of table1 multiplied by 1 = table1).

This is acceptable as long as the value represents what you want to express (i.e., remove the where condition and it will produce the grand total of all patients).

```
select zipcode,
       zipsource,
       sum(patientcount) as patientcount,
       Total,
       concat(round(100*sum_patientcount/Total),'%') as `SHRMC_%`
  from table1,
       (select count(*) as Total
          from table1
         where zipsource='SHRMC') as total
 where zipsource='SHRMC'
 group by zipcode
   having sum(patientcount)/total >= .2
```

Comment: This produced the error mytable.zip_source is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GroupBy clause.  It produced this same error when I had the HAVING clause in there.  Thank you for the response.  The below query does work.